# Spring boot controller URL validation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I have some Sprint controller Mapping like below.

```
@GetMapping("/hello/{name}/age")
    private String hello(@PathVariable(value = "name", required = true) String name){
        //...
    }

   @GetMapping("/hello/{name}")
    private String hello(@PathVariable(value = "name", required = true) String name){
        //...
    }

    @GetMapping("/name")
    private ResponseEntity<?> queryPerson(@RequestParam(value = "query", required = false) String query) {
        // ...
    }
```

But there is a client expetection to handle the below case

when client sends **/hello/john/age**, I should return age related pojo but when client calls **/hello//age** I have to return 400 with invalid user name as error.

Since im my code I already have other mapping hello/{name} so it is calling this API and trying to find username='age' and returing 404.

Here I am suppossed to 400 when user calls /hello//age, so how to handle this in spring?

Answer (score 1):

There will be no chance to create a 400.

Tomcat is collapsing the double slashes:

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tomcat-users/201912.mbox/%3C5DEE18E4.4080902@ice-sa.com%3E